# Boost.Asio: Correct way to close socket and stop the timer and call the handler

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

suppose i have class X which encapsulates asio::ip::tcp::socket and deadline_timer. timer is used to break the connection if it is being too slow. Here is X:

```
class X
{
public:
 typedef boost::function<void(const error_code&)> Handler;
 void f(Handler);
 void close();
private:
 void on_connected(const error_code&);
 void on_timeout(const error_code&);
 void on_work_is_done(const error_code&);
 Handler h_;
 socket s_;
 deadline_timer t_;
};
```

The function f does some work (send, receive, ...) and then calls handler like this:

```
void on_work_is_done(const error_code& e)
{
 //swapping handlers to release handler after function exits
 Handler h;
 h.swap(h_);
 h(e);
}
```

During that time the timer t is ticking. So my problem is:
what is a good way to make X::close? close() must close socket s and stop timer t, and it seems very natural that it must call handler h but only after all async operations (on s and t) are cancelled. If there wasn't timer, then the problem is solved:

```
void X::close() { s.close(); }
```

the async operations will be cancelled and on_work_is_done() will be called with err == operation_aborted, this will be passed to handler and then the handler will be released. Everything is ok. But since there are 2 objects and each of them might have some pending async operations, the problem appears to be more complex. Because if we do

```
void X::close() 
{
 s.close(); 
 t.cancel();
}
```

both handlers (on_work_is_done, on_timeout) will be invoked, but we may call swapped handler_(err) from the handler that was invoked last. 
Is there some straightforward solution?

I see the following approaches:

a) add size_t counter_ which will be set to 2 in X::close() and each of handlers will decrease it by 1. So the handler that made counter_ == 0 will invoke handler_(operation_aborted);

b) run t.cancel() and from on_timeout(err) if err == operation_aborted call s.cancel and from on_work_is_done() invoke handler_(operation_aborted)

Or the whole approach is bad and there is a better way?

Comment: yes - in your handlers, detect the error, and if was invoked due to error, then don't do anything(?)

Comment: so do you have two threads working on the same socket and deadline timer ?